# Using "on this test" instead of "by using this test"

Tags: meaning, prepositions

Does "on" has the meaning of "by using"?

> I can't diagnose mental problems just ***by using*** this test. (or just ***by***)

> I can't diagnose mental problems just ***on*** this test.

Can I use the second one instead of the first one?

Comment: nb spelling "can't"

Answer (score 2):

I would use:

> I can't diagnose mental problems just by this test.

If you insist on using "on:"

> I can't diagnose mental problems just on the basis of this test.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, "I can't diagnose mental problems **just on this test**" is perfectly good.

Also

- **just on one data point**
- **just on hearsay**
- **just on what you say**
- **just on that**

NB: comments suggest this might not be standard usage in medical circles.  I suspect regional variations too, even for non-medical usage: "I can't decide just on this test."

Comment: To diagnose someone "on this test" is very uncommon usage in medicine - I have never read or heard of it.

Comment: Some native speakers say that just using ***on*** make the sentence a bit unclear and recommend using ***"going on the test"*** or even ***"by going on the test"***.

1- I can't diagnose mental problems ***going on this test***.

1a-  Just ***going on this test***, I can't diagnose mental problems.

2-  I can't diagnose mental problems just ***by going on this test***.

Comment: @TalhaÖzden, is this to be used in a spoken or written language?

Comment: @Jan What would you use instead of "on" in this sentence?

Comment: I edited my answer.